# I'm trying to get a generic way to wait for a javascript webpages to load without specifying a fixed delay

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, document-ready

I tried execute_script from selenium to return Document.readyState but I'm getting a none type object in return.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
url='https://example.com'
options=Options()
options.set_headless(headless=True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get(url)
state=driver.execute_script("return Document.readyState")
print(state)
if state=='complete':
    html = driver.page_source
```

> type(state) Out[234]: NoneType

Comment: When starting chrome from the command line, you can specify a virtual time budget that executed JavaScript directly. Since I never used selenium, I don't know how that feature is named inside the code.